# Why Prettier adds These Weird Strings in React Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, prettier

I am facing this issue a lot nowadays. After I save the file in my react project, I see these `{" "}` weird strings at the end of almost every line.
For example, this was my code.

```
<ul>
    <li> <span>npm start </span> : to start the project  </li>
    <li> <span>npm build </span> : to build the project  </li>
  </ul>
```

After I saved the file prettier converted it to

```
 <ul>
    <li>
      {" "}
      <span>npm start </span> : to start the project{" "}
    </li>
    <li>
      {" "}
      <span>npm build </span> : to build the project{" "}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and added `{" "}`. Is there any configuration to get rid of this issue?

Comment: To retain the whitespace between e.g. `<li>` and `<span>` even though it's now broken across lines. Did you actually _want_ that whitespace?

Comment: You have a space in your original: `<li> <span>`, and prettier is trying to preserve that.

Comment: @crashmstr but I am looking for a solution if this is the case.

Comment: A solution _to what_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe to the problem I mentioned above. I don't want to have {" "} on every line if I mistakenly put white space between tags.

Comment: Then you'll have to be more careful with your whitespace, Prettier is doing its best with what you've given it. It can't assume it was unintentional, because that would mean the transform wasn't safe.

Comment: Prettier is *opinionated*. It has very few options, mostly with regards to line length. Either don't put in the spaces into your JSX, remove the `{' '}` after, or don't use prettier. I think those are the only options you have.